# When to delete generated file using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a template excel file to generate excel files from it.

My code is as follows (This part is to create a new excel file from the template):

```
string currentFN = PropertyFinalResult[0].Fecha;
        string fixCurrentFN = currentFN.Replace('/', '_');

        string currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        string fixCurrentTime = currentTime.Replace(':', '_');
        string addToFileName = fixCurrentTime.Replace(' ', '_');

        string newFN = fixCurrentFN + "-" + addToFileName;

        string SourceFile = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Template\\ExcelTemplate.xlsx";
        string DestFile = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Template\\" + newFN + ".xlsx";
        //To keep FileName for posterior deletion
        Session["sDestFile"] = DestFile;

        try
        {                
            File.Copy(SourceFile, DestFile);                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblErrorSavingToDB.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
            lblErrorSavingToDB.Visible = true;
        }
```

after that I open the new excel file, insert the records in it and then, stream the file to the user by doing this:

```
//Streaming file to client                    
                string fileName = newFN + ".xlsx";
                Response.Redirect("../Template/" + fileName);
```

Now, my question is, whether the user save or not the file, when should I delete the generated file? I would prefer once the user closes the popup window regarding Open or Save the file. But how to know when the user closes that window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TransmitFile` and then close once the transmission is over. Example:

```
                try
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(path.FullName) + "\"");
                    Response.AddHeader("content-length", path.Length.ToString());
                    Response.TransmitFile(path.FullName);
                    Response.Flush();
                }
                finally
                {
                    File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/"+tpacode+".zip"));
                }
```

Comment: Will this solution wait for the user, whether he Open/Save/or Cancel the file options?

Comment: it doesn't have to, it just flushes the data to the user and sits quietly, whether the user accepts or rejects the file is upto the User, the file - still - reaches the user. @Somebody

Comment: Your solution works, but when trying to open the excel file (.xlsx) a message appears `Excel found unreadable content...`, although the file is opened at the end.

Comment: I solved that issue by adding `Response.End();` just after `Response.Flush();`

Answer (score 1):

When to delete the files (or maybe it's better to say "how long to keep the files") is a question that is best answered by your application's business rules.

In the past, in low-traffic applications, I've used a "clean-up" routine to delete files older than a certain threshold. That clean-up gets performed when a new file is created, and at that time any file in the designated folder that was older than the threshold would be deleted.